# How can I send two arguments to casperjs from php?

Tags: php, parsing, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to send two arguments from php to casperjs, this is my code:

```
echo "myurli: ".$myurli."<br>";
echo "file_path: ".$file_path."<br>";
parser($myurli, $file_path);

function parser($myurli, $file_path) {
    try {
        echo(exec("C:\casperjs\bin\casperjs.exe C:\OpenServer\domains\casper\auth.js $myurli $file_path 2>&1"));
        flush();
    } catch (Exception $exc) {
        echo('Ошибка!');
        echo $exc->getTraceAsString();
    }
}
```

and this is part of my casperjs code:

```
var system = require('system');
var args = system.args;
var myurli = args[4];
var file_path = args[5];
```

When I check these arguments, I get myurli but file_path is [object Object]. What is wrong here?

Comment: Try to debug what you're getting with `console.log(JSON.stringify(args));`

Answer (score 0):

You can give  the arguments to the casper cli:

```
casperjs --variable_1="variable 1" test.js
```

Then you can handle the variable_1 in your casper code:

```
var variable_1 = casper.cli.get('variable');

casper.start(url, function() {
  casper.then(function() {
    casper.echo(variable_1);
  });
});

casper.run();
```

Comment: Is this the solution to your problem described here?